# How I fix this jquery / ajax issue?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I do have 4 text inputs like this,

```
<input type="text" name="amount" id="amount">
<input type="text" name="commission" id="commission">
<input type="text" name="discount" id="discount">
<input type="text" name="total_amount" id="total_amount">
```

Here I am calculating `total_amount` base on the values of `#amount`. To do this I am using ajax like this,

```
var minlength = 2;
$("#amount").on('input', function () {
  var value  = $(this).val(), 
  if (value.length >= minlength ) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "includes/transactions/proccess_amount.php",
      data: {'amount':value},          
      success: function(response) {
        response = jQuery.parseJSON(response)
        $('#make_transaction')
          .find('[name="commission"]').val(response.commission).end()
          .find('[name="total_amount"]').val(response.total_amount).end(); 
      }    
    });
  } 
});
```

Now I want to change `total_amount` again if it has a value on `#discount` field. So I created a ajax request for #discount `keyup` and its working for me.

`keyup` script look like this.

```
var strLength = 1;
$("#discount").keyup(function () {
  var discount = $(this).val(),
      amount   = $('#amount').val(),
      comison  = $('#commission').val(),
      total    = $('#total_amount').val();

      if (discount.length >= strLength ) {
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "includes/transactions/proccess_discount.php",
          data: { 'amount':amount
                , 'comison': comison
                , 'total'   : total
                , 'discount': discount
                },

          success: function(response) {
            response = jQuery.parseJSON(response)
            $('#amount_dolar').val(''); 
            $('#make_transaction')
              .find('[name="amount_dolar"]').val(response.amount).end()
              .find('[name="total_amount"]').val(response.totalAfterDiscount).end();
          }

        });
      }
    });
```

My problem is I want to display previous `total_amount` when discount field is empty. At this stage it is always displaying the total with discount.

Update: 
Image with the output for better understanding. 
[image]

Can anybody tell how to do this? 
Thank you.

Comment: `total    = $('#total_amount').val(),` <--- trailing comma...

Comment: Could use the `else` of this: `if (discount.length >= strLength ) {` or `elseif(discount == ""){}`

Comment: What is exactly in response.totalAfterDiscount in the test case you are talking about? "" or undefined or ???

Comment: @epascarello, `#amount` ajax call is ignoring discount value and it creates total amount with `amount + commission`. `#discount` ajax call is considering discount value and regenerating total amount.

Comment: @epascarello, I updated my question with an image for better understanding. Please look at it. Thank you.

Comment: Why have two different backends? Have one end point that returns back both items.

Comment: Because discount field should be changeable by users. That mean they can test 5%, 10%, 15% etc. for same amount. Thats why I used separate backend for discount field.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having the #amount ajax call again in the 'success' section of the response to the #discount call.  The problem seems to be that the #amount ajax is calling proccess_amount.php and the #discount ajax is calling proccess_discount.php.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the initial total amount in cookie on keyup of discount input where you are making ajax call and when discount gets  null or empty, put that total account from cookie to total amount input.

Comment: Anil Panwar, can you show me an example of how to do it? Thank you.

Comment: Inside your $("#discount").keyup(function(){ $.cookie('previouAmount', $("total_amount").val()); });   and later get it from cookie and put in amount input if discount gets empty.

Comment: Anil, Still Iam not sure how to use it. Please elaborate it. Thank you.

Comment: Do I need to install `jquery.cookie` for this?

Comment: Check out this link about how to set and get cookie and hope this will fix it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-to-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery

Comment: If you don't like this approch than you can make hidden input containing the total amount and can copy later this input value if the discount gets empty. Or you can set attribute to any input like this < input type="text" data-Amount="345" value="345" > later get this data-Amount if the discount gets empty.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends in what is in `response.totalAfterDiscount`

Easy solution is to use the or operator `||`

```
.val(response.totalAfterDiscount || response.amount)
```

BUT the problem with that is the fact if the totalAfterDiscount is zero (could be a 100% off sale) than it would show amount and not the discount.

So next option depends on what totalAfterDiscount holds when there is no discount.

If it holds an empty string

```
.val(response.totalAfterDiscount.length ?  response.totalAfterDiscount : response.amount)
```

If it is undefined

```
.val(response.totalAfterDiscount!==undefined ? response.totalAfterDiscount : response.amount)
```

Comment: Total amount is calculating `amount + commission`. But `response.amount` have only the values of `amount field.

Comment: So swap `response.amount` to whatever it should be.

Comment: Yes, I realized this line is not needed at all `.find('[name="amount_dolar"]').val(response.amount).end()` isn't it?